# AngularJS - Page Not Displaying New User Name On Load

Tags: angularjs

On my localhost, when I login as a user, it displays the username at the top of the page. After I logout, and login as a different user, it still displays the username of the previous user. Then, when I press refresh once, the username is updated. Have I made a mistake in my controller that is not allowing this to update on page load, rather than me having to hit refresh?

the doLogin() is the function my form is calling when I hit submit. Auth.getUser() is getting the user data.

My controller:

```
var app = angular.module('mainCtrl', [])

.controller('mainController', function($rootScope, $location, Auth) {

    var vm = this;

    // get info if a person is logged in
    vm.loggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn();

    // check to see if a user is logged in on every request
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
        vm.loggedIn = Auth.isLoggedIn();    

        // get user information on page load
        Auth.getUser()
            .then(function(data) {
                vm.user = data.data;
            }); 
    }); 

    // function to handle login form
    vm.doLogin = function() {
        vm.processing = true;

        // clear the error
        vm.error = '';

        Auth.login(vm.loginData.username, vm.loginData.password)
            .success(function(data) {
                vm.processing = false;          

                // if a user successfully logs in, redirect to users page
                if (data.success) {
                $location.path('/users');
                } else {
                    vm.error = data.message;
                }
            });
    };

    // function to handle logging out
    vm.doLogout = function() {
        Auth.logout();
        vm.user = '';
        $location.path('/');
    };
});
```

My Auth factory for getting the user:

```
// get the logged in user
authFactory.getUser = function() {
    if (AuthToken.getToken())
        return $http.get('/api/me', { cache: true });
    else
        return $q.reject({ message: 'User has no token.' });        
};
```

HTML that displays the username:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li ng-if="!main.loggedIn"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
        <li ng-if="main.loggedIn" class="navbar-text">Hello {{ main.user.name }}!</li>
        <li ng-if="main.loggedIn"><a href="#" ng-click="main.doLogout()">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: if you're using chrome, try putting `debugger;` somewhere in the code and step through from there

Comment: Sounds like a caching problem.

Comment: That worked for me, thank you!